# Print with elegance the resulsts of a Query

Tags: java, database

I am programming an app where the user can connect to a MySQL db and execute some queries.

I'm putting the results in a ResultSet but I can't find an elegant way to print the result to a textArea.

Does java have some class specifically to print the results of a query?

Comment: show the sample code of your current approach and tell us where does it lacks

Comment: It doesnt lack in programming logic.I can see the results but it is not elegant in the eye.For example my result is something like : |id | name | age|........I want a table like apperance like in MySQL workbench or SQL server.

Comment: text Area?? What text area? SHOW CODE or we can't see what you mean.

Comment: You're asking how to justify columns? Why use a text area? Use a table, or a library that has table views, etc.

Comment: Your question quality is very low so you have to show some code that you have acheived till now  and add more explanation to your question this will help you getting more response that you are not getting now

Answer (score 0):

Map tables to classes and result queries too. For example, you have a table Users in your database and you want get all these users and print them on the JTextArea.

```
public class User {

    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;

    // constructors, getters and setters

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ID: " + id +
        "\nFirst name: " + firstName +
        "\nLast name: " + lastName +
        "\nEmail: " + email;
    }
}
```

In your DAO:

```
public List<User> getAllUsers() {
    List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();

    try(Connection con = ConnectionHelper.get();
        Statement st = con.createStatement()) {
            String query = "SELECT * FROM User";
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);

            // check if resultset is empty
            if(!rs.isBerforeFirst()) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Not users found");
            }
            // iterate over result set and wrap
            // data in User bean
            while(rs.next()) {
                User user = new User();
                user.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
                user.setFirstName(rs.getString("firstname"));
                user.setLastname(rs.getString("lastname"));
                user.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
                users.add(user);
            }
    } catch(SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error when fetch users", e);
    }

    return users;
}
```

In your controller or view:

```
try {
    UserDao dao = new UserDao();
    List<User> allUsers = dao.getAllUsers();
    for(User user : allUsers) {
        textArea.append(user); // implicit call toString
    }

} catch(RuntimeException e) {
    // log 'Not users found' or 'Error when fetch users'
    Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName())
        .log(Level.SEVERE. e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```